# Question about generic points of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

A point $p$ in a topological space $X$ is said to be generic if $\overline{\{p\}} =X$ (i.e. $\{p\}$ is dense in $X$).

Let $G(X)=\{p \mid p\text{ is generic in }X\}$. That is, $G(X)$ is the set of all the points dense in $X$.

$X$ path-connected if $G(X)$ is nonempty.

Show $G(X)$ is a compact subspace of $X$.

Comment: Yes, it was part (a) of the question which I had to prove. (Show X is path-connected if G(X) is nonempty)

Comment: Not sure if that's even relevant to part b but put it in there in case!

Comment: Hint: "$\{ p \}$ is dense" means "every nonempty open set contains $p$".

Comment: Yes, p is an element of every open set of X was also used for part (a). I tried to work with it but dislike where I was going!

Comment: If G(x) is finite is easy, I am running into a problem if G(X) is infinite

Comment: Ahh I got turned around. You're quite right about (a). How bizarre!

Comment: If G(X) is finite I consider the smallest open sets containing each p in G(X) which implies a finite subcollection of open covers. But what if G(X) is infinite?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much to add to Chris' hint in the comment. Since every nonempty open set contains every point of $G(X)$, given any cover of $G(X)$, every element of the cover contains all of $G(X)$, so every element forms a finite subcover of $G(X)$ by itself.

Comment: Why does every nonempty open set contain EVERY point of G(X)?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand! Every point in G(X) is an element of each open set, which implies every open set contains every element of G(X)!

Comment: I was reading too much into it! Thanks guys!